# What is $\int_{y}^{y+\epsilon}f(x)dx\,$?

Tags: integration

If we have this integral

$$\int_{y}^{y+\epsilon}f(x)dx$$

What is the result of that integral? How do you get it? Can you show it is equal to *f(y)*? I am confused about how to solve it.

Comment: I don't think it is well defined to have same variables in the limits as after the $d$. Maybe $\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\epsilon}f(x)dx$ so it is clear it is an interval after a specific point $x_0$?

Comment: mm..yes or maybe a continuous variable as $y$? It is the same as when you write derivatives as f(x+dx)-f(x), what is the point? Thanks

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then your integral is $F(y+\epsilon)-F(y)$. If you take the limit of this expression as $\epsilon\to0$, you recover $f$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I think that to recover $f$ there must be a $\frac{1}{e}$ multiplying the integral. Am i wrong?

Comment: @santimirandarp: whoops, yes, left off that detail.

Comment: Great, thank you @symplectomorphic

Comment: @symplectomorphic would you complete the answer? So someone with the same doubt will be helped

Comment: You may write it as $$\epsilon \frac{F(y+\epsilon)-F(y)}{\epsilon}$$  As $\epsilon \to 0$ then we have,  $$\sim \epsilon f(y)$$ Otherwise we have that the quantity is $\approx f(y) \epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus your integral evaluates to

$$F(y+\epsilon)-F(y)$$

If you'd like to recover $f$, you can multiply your integral by $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and take the limit as $\epsilon\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the integral between $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ ( where $x+\epsilon$  most likely just means a value higher than $x$)

Now to solve this definite integral

$$\int_x^{x+\epsilon} f(x) dx = f(x)$$ according to what you said

A good example of a function with an integral equal to itself is $e^x$ So perhaps this is the answer youre looking for

Comment: I think it is little more than that. But, anyway, thanks.